# CSS - How to properly use flex-basis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I am setting up my own Grid Component. I made a Row Component where it has a `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap` and dynamic `gap`, `column-gap`, and `row-gap`. I have a Column Component where I set a dynamic flex basis. I tried to use it like this:

```
<Row :gap="30">
  <Column :w="50">
    Text
  </Column>
  <Column :w="50">
    Text
  </Column>
  <Column :w="50">
    Text
  </Column>
</Row>
```

I'm converting the `50` to percentage as flex-basis. It turns out that it wraps all the items because of the gap. Am I using the flex-basis wrong? Is there another way to setup my columns?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a length in flex-basis, you're specifying the length of individual items along the flex axis. When you specify a percentage this way, the percentage is equal to a fraction of the parent container's size! You can see this in [MDN's flex-basis definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis), in the section on "Values" which explains the possible values you can give this property:

> **<'width'>**
> An absolute <length>, a <percentage> of the parent flex container's main size property, or the keyword auto. Negative values are invalid. Defaults to auto.

This means, assuming your flex is oriented as a row:

- If you specify `flex-basis: 200px`, the flex items will each have a width of 200px.
- If you specify `flex-basis: 25%`, the flex items will each have a width of 25% of the parent width. If the parent container is 100px, they will each have a width of 25px.

For the purposes of flex wrapping, any gap defined has to be respected in addition to the flex basis. If you have `flex-basis: 25%` plus a 25% gap, that flex item occupies 50% of the width of the container.

It's no surprise your rows are wrapping — you've defined them collectively as 150% of their parent width! The gap would also exacerbate things: a 50% width plus any gap means the cell has to occupy more than half the horizontal space, so there's no possibility to have columns.

If you want fractional sizing along a row, where each element takes up an equal share of its parent width, you should be using CSS Grid with `grid-auto-columns: 1fr`. This is especially if you want cell gaps: when you define grid cells with fractional sizes *and* a gap, both can be respected simultaneously.

The below snippet demonstrates the following things:

1. Defining an exact flex-basis in a flex box with 200px width
2. Defining a percentage flex-basis in an identical flex box
3. Using CSS Grid in one single row
4. Using CSS Grid with wrapping

```css
.flex-absolute-width,
.flex-relative-width,
.grid,
.grid-wrapped {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  gap: 8px;
}

.cell {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.flex-absolute-width,
.flex-relative-width {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-absolute-width .cell {
  flex-basis: 50px;
}

.flex-relative-width .cell {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; /* each column shares 1fr width */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* prefer to flow into new columns */
}

.grid-wrapped {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
Flex-basis 50px:
<div class="flex-absolute-width">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">b</div>
  <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>

Flex-basis 50%:
<div class="flex-relative-width">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">b</div>
  <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>

A grid with each column being told to use the same fraction of width:
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">b</div>
  <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>

A wrapped grid with each column being told to use the same fraction of width:
<div class="grid-wrapped">
  <div class="cell">a</div>
  <div class="cell">b</div>
  <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your third example but it does not wrap. My goal is whatever width I set on the child will fit accordingly with a wrap. For example if I set the width to 50% It should have 2 elements there but still has a gap with like 10px for example. When I have 5 items, it should have 3 rows.

Comment: @RyanGarde Ok, I see. There's a use in grid for that.

Comment: I partially solved it but I removed the gap. I replaced it with padding and added a negative x-margin on the parent. I won't post this as answer for now. I really like to use gap because it has a lot of configuration dynamically and I want to use column-gap and row-gap too

Comment: @RyanGarde I've added an example of CSS grid with wrapping and a gap.

Answer (score -2):

```css
#main {
  width: 270px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

#main div {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50px;
}
```

```html
<row id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">50px</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">50px</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">50px</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">50px</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">50px</div>
</row>
```